# File layoutlib.jar doesnt exist

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio 1.5.1 and install every package needed using SDK Manager. I choose to use API 21 and install all the package under this API. But when I open a project, i get no preview but this.

```
File C:\Users\uyung\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-21\data\layoutlib.jar doesnt exist
```

Some people suggest to install another API package. But unfortunately I have limit storage at my partition. Any idea to make the preview work?

Comment: for everyone getting this error, just remove the package and download again through sdk manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i delet my sdk platform and downlod it again. error fixed.